# Calculating averaged data in and writing to csv from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average, export-to-csv

I have a very large spatial dataset stored in a dataframe. I am taking a slice of that dataframe into a new smaller subset to run further calculations.
The data has x, y and z coordinates with a number of additional columns, some of which are text and some are numeric. The x and y coordinates are on a defined grid and have a known separation.
Data looks like this

```
x,y,z,text1,text2,text3,float1,float2
75000,45000,120,aa,bbb,ii,12,0.2
75000,45000,110,bb,bbb,jj,22,0.9
75000,45100,120,aa,bbb,ii,11,1.8
75000,45100,110,bb,bbb,jj,45,2.4
75000,45100,100,bb,ccc,ii,13.6,1
75100,45000,120,bb,ddd,jj,8.2,2.1
75100,45000,110,bb,ddd,ii,12,0.6
```

For each x and y pair I want to iterate over a two series of text values and do three things in the z direction.

1. Calculate the average of one numeric value for all the values with a third specific text value
2. Sum another numeric value for all the values with the same text value
3. Write the a resultant table of 'x, y, average, sum' to a csv.

My code does part three (albeit very slowly) but doesn't calculate 1 or 2 or at least I don't appear to get the average and sum calculations in my output.

What have I done wrong and how can I speed it up?

```
    for text1 in text_list1:
        for text2 in text_list2:
            # Get the data into smaller dataframe
            df = data.loc[ (data["textfield1"] == text1) & (data["textfield2"] == text2 ) ]
                
            #Get the minimum and maximum x and y 
            minXw = df['x'].min()
            maxXw = df['x'].max()
            minYw = df['y'].min()
            maxYw = df['y'].max()
            
            # dictionary for quicker printing
            dict_out  = {}
            rows_list = []
            
            # Make output filename
            filenameOut = text1+"_"+text2+"_Values.csv"
            # Start looping through x values
            for x in np.arange(minXw, maxXw, x_inc):
                xcount += 1
                # Start looping through y values
                for y in np.arange(minYw, maxYw, y_inc):
                    ycount += 1
                    
                    # calculate average and sum
                    ave_val = df.loc[df['textfield3'] == 'text3', 'float1'].mean()
                    sum_val = df.loc[df['textfield3'] == 'text3', 'float2'].sum()

                    # Make Dictionary of output values
                    dict_out  = dict([('text1', text1), 
                                      ('text2', text2), 
                                      ('text3', df['text3']),
                                      ('x'    , x-x_inc),
                                      ('y'    , y-y_inc),
                                      ('ave'  , ave_val),
                                      ('sum'   , sum_val)])
                    rows_list_c.append(dict_out)

            # Write csv      
            columns = ['text1','text2','text3','x','y','ave','sum']
            with open(filenameOut, 'w') as csvfile:
                writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=columns)
                writer.writeheader()
                for data in dict_out:
                    writer.writerow(data)
```

My resultant csv gives me:

```
text1,text2,text3,x,y,ave,sum

text1,text2,,74737.5,43887.5,nan,0.0
text1,text2,,74737.5,43912.5,nan,0.0
text1,text2,,74737.5,43937.5,nan,0.0
text1,text2,,74737.5,43962.5,nan,0.0
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show sample input data and intended output. Your average and sum will be summary measures for each value of `textfield3`, so how can x, y and z be shown in the same output table?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer.
Z isn't necessary in the output and x and y can be taken from the loop. These bits work as shown in the current output. It seems to be the ave and sum values and texts that don't get populated in my output. Which are the values in trying to pull from the dataframe

Comment: It looks like probably there are no cases where `(data["textfield1"] == text1) & (data["textfield2"] == text2 )` and `df['textfield3'] == 'text3'` - is it possible the column names or values are incorrect? Can you try to show code consistent with the example input you have given, including what is in `text_list1` and `text_list2`?

Comment: I'll check the true input data but I am certain that all three text values exist together. If I'm wrong you just fixed my problem :).

Comment: There seem to be other problems - you are looping through `x` and `y` but the average and sum will be the same each time (for each value of `text1` and `text2`). This is also what makes it slow - depending on the `x_inc` and `y_inc` you are repeating the same operation lots of times. Look into `groupby` and `agg`.

Comment: X and y are real spatial coordinates with their own unique data and although in many cases the values might be the same i need to output each pair to provide an averaged dataset for every value. x_inc and y_inc are set at the exact value to increment to the next vertical (z) group of xy paired values. I'll look up groupby and agg

Comment: Yes but you're not averaging within those values of `x` and `y` - you're redoing the same average in each step.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought by incrementing x and y separately I would loop through all the unique combinations of x and y only once. We should see all of the y coordinates at each x position only once. Where am I repeating them? Is my dataframe at this point not specific to only my x an y coordinates?

Comment: Would df.loc[ (df['x']==x) & (df['y']==y)] resolve that

Comment: Yes that would resolve it, provided the values of `x` and `y` are exact (rather than in a range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really clear what you're trying to do. But here is a starting point

If you only need to process rows with a specific `text3`value, start by filtering out the other rows:

```
df = df[df.text3=="my_value"]
```

If at this point, you do not need text3 anymore, you can also drop it

```
df = df.drop(columns="text3")
```

Then you process several sub dataframes, and write each of them to their own csv file. [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) is the perfect tool for that:

```
for (text1, text2), sub_df in df.groupby(["text1", "text2"]):
    filenameOut = text1+"_"+text2+"_Values.csv"
    # Process sub df
    output_df = process(sub_df)
    # Write sub df
    output_df.to_csv(filenameOut)
```

Note that if you keep your data as a DataFrame instead of converting it to a dict, you can use the DataFrame [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method to simply write the output csv.

Now let's have a look at the process function (Note that you dont really need to make it a separate function, you could as well dump the function body in the for loop).

At this point, if I understand correctly, you want to compute the sum and the average of every rows that have the same x and y coordinates. Here again you can use `groupby` and the [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) function to compute the mean and the sum of the group.

```
def process(sub_df):
   # drop the text1 and text2 columns since they are in the filename anyway
   out = sub_df.drop(columns=["text1","text2"])
   
   # Compute mean and max
   return out.groupby(["x", "y"]).agg(ave=("float1", "mean"), sum=("float2", "sum"))
```

And that's preety much it.

**Bonus: 2-liner version** (but don't do that...)

```
for (text1, text2), sub_df in df[df.text3=="my_value"].drop(columns="text3").groupby(["text1", "text2"]):
    sub_df.drop(columns=["text1","text2"]).groupby(["x", "y"]).agg(ave=("float1", "mean"), sum=("float2", "sum")).to_csv(text1+"_"+text2+"_Values.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this in an efficient way in pandas you will need to use `groupby`, `agg` and the in-built `to_csv` method rather than using `for` loops to construct lists of data and writing each one with the `csv` module. Something like this:

```
groups = data[data["text1"].isin(text_list1) & data["text2"].isin(text_list2)] \
    .groupby(["text1", "text2"])

for (text1, text2), group in groups:
    group.groupby("text3") \
        .agg({"float1": np.mean, "float2": sum}) \
        .to_csv(f"{text1}_{text2}_Values.csv")
```

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do with the incrementing of `x` and `y` values, which is also what makes your current code very slow. To present sums and averages of the floating point columns by intervals of `x` and `y`, you could make bin columns and group by those too.

```
data["x_bin"] = (data["x"] - data["x"].min()) // x_inc
data["y_bin"] = (data["y"] - data["y"].min()) // y_inc
groups = data[data["text1"].isin(text_list1) & data["text2"].isin(text_list2)] \
    .groupby(["text1", "text2"])

for (text1, text2), group in groups:
    group.groupby(["text3", "x_bin", "y_bin"]) \
        .agg({"x": "first", "y": "first", "float1": np.mean, "float2": sum}) \
        .to_csv(f"{text1}_{text2}_Values.csv")
```